# Dojo datagrid in dialog causes parse error on load

Tags: datagrid, dojo, dialog

I am trying to use a dojo datagrid in a dojo dialog and I get the following dojo/parse error when trying to load the page.

dojo/parser::parse() error (new TypeError("d(...) is undefined", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox//grid/DataGrid.js", 16))

If I comment out the require DataGrid statement, the parse error goes away.  Notice I am not even trying to create a data grid yet.  Just trying to build a bare bones page.

The following is the code for the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dojo Dialog with DataGrid</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/grid/resources/Grid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
        <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
        <script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Button"]);
            require([
                "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                "dojox/grid/cells",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector",
                "dojo/domReady!",
            ]);
            //var grid2x;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myFormDialog" title="Form Dialog"
    execute="alert('submitted w/args:\n' + dojo.toJson(arguments[0], true));">

        <div class="dijitDialogPaneContentArea">
        </div>

        <div class="dijitDialogPaneActionBar">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" onClick="return myFormDialog.isValid();">
                OK
            </button>
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog.hide()">
                Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>When pressing this button the dialog will popup:</p>
    <button id="buttonThree" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="button" onClick="myFormDialog.show();">
        Show me!
    </button>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this post is old, your problem seems to be the comma after `"dojo/domReady!,"` There should be no comma after the last import. Also load all that you want to load in the first require i.e instead of having `<script>
            require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Button"]);
            require([
                "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                "dojox/grid/cells",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector",
                "dojo/domReady!",
            ]);
            //var grid2x;
        </script>`
Just put all in one require as follows:
`<script>
            require(["dojo/parser", 
        "dijit/Dialog", 
        "dijit/form/Button",
        "dojox/grid/DataGrid",
                "dojox/grid/cells",
                "dojo/store/Memory",
                "dojo/data/ObjectStore",
                "dojo/_base/array",
                "dojo/_base/lang",
                "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector",
                "dojo/domReady!"]);

            //var grid2x;
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

problem is `<html lang="en">`. parser can't parse html components if lang="en". Remove it or override with `data-dojo-config="lang='en-us'"`